# how do i get the content of a webview

Tags: android

I need to create an android browser in Yoruba language. I have already used webviews to create one in English language. What i wnt to do is to get the content of each page as it loads.

If i can get the whole content of a page into an array, i will be happy so i can now send the content to google translate api to translate to Yoruba and the some how i will replace the engliah in the html with the Yoruba strings.

I want to be able to do this on the fly before the page finish loading.

I have already developed an engliah browser and i know how to work with api. I just need to get the content of a webview page into an array and be able to replace after translation

Comment: If you already have the WebView to show the English version of Web pages, you can plug in Google Website Translator and switch language presentation on the fly without any change in your code other than inserting the code provided from Google. Here is the link: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: I already have a working webview that loads web pages in English IsabelHM I checked the link, it's meant for website owners to put the toolbox on their website. Can i put it in my android code. Btw  it's asking me what website i want to paste it on. Thans so much, pls reply

Comment: Note: i am creating a browser and so it will be visiting numerous webpages that dont belong to me. So i cant add the translate plugin to them